# Help with finding the function that satisfies conditions of a Fourier Sine Integral Coefficient

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I understand that the following function is the Fourier Sine Coefficient for the function. However, I am having trouble finding the function that can satisfy such conditions. How do I go about finding the function that satisfies the following conditions?

$$\int_0^L f(x) \sin(wx)dx=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{$0\leq w \leq 1$,}\\
2, & \text{$1\leq w \leq 2$,}\\
0, & \text{$w \geq 2.$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Are you sure the integral is over $(0,\infty)$ and not $(0,L)$?

Comment: I believe the question will have a real limit, so yes $(0,L)$ is correct. Sorry about that. I've made the correction.